# What code libraries are there to rip audio CDs that are suitable for commerical use?

Tags: audio, freebsd, extract, cd, ripping

What code libraries are there to rip audio CDs (e.g. DAE, Digital Audio Extraction)?  Must be suitable for commerical use (e.g., no GPL) Preferably free.  Linux or FreeBSD or Windows.  Most interested in libraries that run on unix-like OS's, especially FreeBSD.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in Windows-only, I believe you can use the Windows Media Player control to rip CDs.  It's built into Windows and thus shouldn't have any royalty issues.

If you need something that runs cross-platform, it may be more challenging.

Comment: Thanks thats good to know.  I don't need cross platform.  Although I would prefer something that runs on freebsd.  I'll edit my question to reflect this.